# Modifying “ALIEN Deviation” Pen - - issue with HTML canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas

**SUMMARY**

There is an out of place rectangular red box at the bottom of my screen.

**BACKGROUND**

Using Chrome’s Developer Tools on my local dev workspace, I’ve pin-pointed the source of the  issue to a relatively newly introduced canvas element, which I don’t fully understand. I’ve explored [w3school’s doc](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) along with [Chris Coyier’s main blog post on HTML canvas](https://css-tricks.com/learn-canvas-snake-game/) and I don’t really understand how to use the canvas element properly in this situation.

**MY CODE**

[Here is my reduced test case on CodePen.](https://codepen.io/angeles4four-the-lessful/pen/bXrZbB)

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="title">

<!-- Original concept borrowed from Marco Dell'Anna in a CodePen titled ALIEN - Deviation of microcosm, source: https://codepen.io/plasm/pen/JNPXxg  -->

<h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>

<h3><a href="#">@ hyperlink 1</a></h3> 

<h3><a href="#">@ hyperlink 2</a></h3> 

<h3><a href="#">@ hyperlink 3</a></h3> 

<h3><a href="#">@ hyperlink 6</a></h3> 

  <br />
   <br />
    <br />

<h3><a href="#">~ hyperlink  @ random ~</a></h3> 
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,600");
.more-pens {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 12px;
}

a.white-mode, a.white-mode:link, a.white-mode:visited, a.white-mode:active {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #212121;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #f7f7f7;
}
a.white-mode:hover, a.white-mode:link:hover, a.white-mode:visited:hover, a.white-mode:active:hover {
  background: #edf3f8;
  color: #212121;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;*/
  height: 100%;
  background: crimson;
  color: white;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100% !important;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  z-index: -1;
}

.title {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 30px;
}
.title h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 135%;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 20px white;
}
.title h1 span {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #BBB;
}
.title h3 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 30px #000155;
  line-height: 175%;

}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 20px white;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}


h2 {color: white;}
```

I believe this issue is not specific to the JavaScript.

**ACTUAL/EXPECTED RESULT**

The actual parsed HTML and CSS shows a red (crimson) rectangular box at the bottom of the window/screen, [as it appears in this image on imgur](https://imgur.com/mOyX56x). This issue is apparent more so at narrower resolutions. You may need to reduce the width of your web browser and scroll your mouse wheel down to see the issue I am referring to. I am expecting my webpage to appear without the red rectangular box.

How might you do to fix this? What property or value may be necessary to eliminate this red box?

I get that I am seeing the rectangle because the title class does not go the full height of my screen, so the rest is the body element bleeding through. But I am not sure how to rectify this.

Again, [here is my reduced test case on CodePen](https://codepen.io/angeles4four-the-lessful/pen/bXrZbB). For what it is worth, [here is the original “ALIEN Deviation” that my Pen is based on.](https://codepen.io/plasm/pen/JNPXxg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crimson is red change background: crimson; to whatever background color you wish.

Added:

Change this portion of .title

```
.title {
   padding: 50px 30px;
}
```

to

```
.title {
   padding: 50px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

I can only replicate it if the scroll bar appears on the browser. You are setting the height of the canvas to the visible view port and not the entire view port height. When you scroll the browser window, the canvas scrolls up to reveal the spacing.

Change position:absolute to position:fix in the CSS .canvas part.

```
canvas {
   position : fixed;
}
```

Comment: At line 35 inside the body element in my CSS, if I change the color from 'crimson' to 'yellow' or to 'green' or even to 'none', the rectangle does not disappear. The box just changes color (while still interfering with the content text). See here: https://imgur.com/0caczs4

Comment: The idea was to change the crimson to the dark blue to match the color in the canvas background. I've added some more info to remove the padding if that works for you better.

Comment: If we change the background to dark blue, you are right that the rectangle box becomes harder to see. But the background needs to be dynamic with the squiggly red lines presented by the JavaScript. Changing the body background color as you suggest doesn't really resolve the issue because the body background still covers the animated squiggly lines. I've added `padding: 50px 30px 0px 30px;` to the .title element which doesn't remove the rectangle box either.

Comment: Added the bit about position:fixed

Comment: Thanks, John! Adding the `fixed` value to the `position` property in the `.canvas` class did it!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve other than removing the red box.

> Remove your `title` class or adjust it.

Since the css properties of it as per the original example was purposely for centered shorter contents. From their, adjust the css code to your desire. You can also just removed other properties of `title` class then just leave `position:absolute` if you desire to set the texts in fixed position.

Comment: You are right that all I am trying to achieve is to remove the red box.

When I swap out the `position` property's value from `relative` to `absolute` (in the `.title h1` element in the CSS), the crimson red rectangle does disappear. But then the `h1` is centered on the page and overlaps the `h3`'s, which is not what I want. Anyways, I've taken your other suggestion to adjust my title class. I have since taken the ending .title divider in the HTML and moved it above the paragraph tag and am now adjusting my CSS from there. Thank you for the suggestion.